# How to prevent Firebase Cloud Function from crashing and how to send error message as response?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I've created a simple `createUser` function which is executed on call. I have one problem though. The function is crashing when the user is trying to register with an already existing email. I mean, it's ok, since no one wants to have 2 users with the same email address but I want to prevent crushing function, instead, I want to send an error message as a response.

```
export const createUserTest = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const {email, password} = data;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    try{
      admin
           .auth()
           .createUser({
             email: email,
             emailVerified: false,
             password: password,
             disabled: false,
           })
           .then((user) => {
             resolve({
                 result: 'success',
                 user: user,
             }) ;
           })
           .catch((error) => {
             reject(error) ;
           });
    }catch(error) {
      reject (error)
    }  
  })  
});
```

I tried to put the function in to `try/catch` block but it didn't help. Do you have an idea of how I can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors) for Callable Cloud Functions, "to ensure the client gets useful error details, return errors from a callable by throwing (or returning a Promise rejected with) an instance of `functions.https.HttpsError`".

The error has a `code` attribute that can be one of the values listed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_#functionserrorcode). In your case, the most appropriate seems to be `already-exists`.

On, the other hand, you'll find [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors) the Admin SDK Authentication errors list and you'll see that in case the provided email is already in use by an existing user the error code is `auth/email-already-exists`.

So you can adapt your code as follows:

```
export const createUserTest = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const { email, password } = data;

    return admin
        .auth()
        .createUser({
            email: email,
            emailVerified: false,
            password: password,
            disabled: false,
        })
        .then((user) => {
            return {
                result: 'success',
                user: user,
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-exists') {
                throw new functions.https.HttpsError('already-exists', 'The provided email is already in use by an existing user');
            } else {
                throw new functions.https.HttpsError('...other code....', '...');
                // If an error other than HttpsError is thrown, your client instead receives an error with the message INTERNAL and the code internal.
            }
        });

});
```

See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors_on_the_client) in the doc, how to handle errors on the client side. If `error.code == 'already-exists'` you know that it's because the email is already in use.